# Stream from soundcloud API without user authentication

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I am building an HTML5 soundcloud player that will stream tracks of a specific (artist)user ONLY. Soundcloud tells me to hardcode the user's credentials and use the **Authentication without Connect Screen** method.

In my case, I want to avoid that because the user created his SC account using Facebook and has no credentials. Since, I can get information about tracks, comments etc without authentication. My question.

> Is it possible to stream a track with just clientid, no user authentication?

Currently, a get request to the stream_url yields a 401 Unauthorized Error.

```
$.get(stream_url+'&client_id='+clientid,function(e){
console.log(e)}
```

401 Error Unauthorized

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Playing tracks with the JavaScript API does not require authentication/login, just the Client ID of your API Application:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: '{CLIENT_ID}'
});

SC.stream('tracks/107686148').then(function(player) {
    player.play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the properties of the particular track – if user has set their track to be private and/or non-embeddable etc. then it's not going to be possible.

However, if the track is public, you should be able to stream with just `client_id`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The tracks are public, but it still fails.